# Removing ' \ ' from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, gsub

I need to remove '\' from a string wherever it appears on it in ruby on rails. Is it possible using gsub or anything similar to it ?

For example consider a string, string = "hey boss\ how are you".
I need to make it to print as "hey boss how are you".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using:

```
'hey boss\ how are you'.gsub('\\',' ')     

=> "hey boss how are you"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'hey boss\ how are you'.tr('\\','')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'hey boss\ how are you'.delete!('\\')
   => "hey boss how are you"
```